# Set a timeout for database connection with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is it somehow possible to set a connection timeout in Doctrine (for MySQL)?

I would like to set a 5 sec. timeout for my connections.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to specify the driver option for connection timeouts in your services.yaml configuration for doctrine dbal (seeing your symfony tag).

If you're using mysqli extension:

```yaml
doctrine:
  dbal:
    ...
    options:
        0: 5 // '0' is the value of 'MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
```

For PDO-based drivers:

```yaml
doctrine:
  dbal:
    ...
    options:
        2: 5 // '2' is the value of 'PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT'
```

References:

- https://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration
- https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/configuration.html
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php#pdo.constants.attr-timeout

Answer (score 1):

If you're finding this question and using SQL Server:
I'm using SQL Server, not MySQL, with a PDO driver, Symfony 5, and Doctrine ORM 2.7.4.

Using PDO enum values in the `services.yaml` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62070107/1084945) did not work; the initial connection times out after 30 seconds regardless of the value I set with `PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT`.

Instead, the [LoginTimeout](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php) value can be used:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    ...
    options:
        LoginTimeout: 5
```

Note that the options set in the YAML here are passed into the `$dnsOptions` array used to construct the `$dsn` in `PDOSqlsrv/Driver::_constructPdoDsn()`, so setting a raw PDO enum value (`2=5`, as in the linked answer, for example) may not be what you want do.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can use something like set_time_limit() into your script execution