# How to change the timed out time when trying to login to databse?

Tags: php, symfony, connection, php-8

I want to check if we can't connect to the database with symfony 6.2.6.

I'm using this code:

```php
$conn = $doctrine->getConnection($dbName);
try {
    $conn->connect();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    return "Failed to use database: " $e->getMessage();
}
if(!$conn->isConnected()) {
    return "Could not connect to database";
}
return "Fine !";
```

I have this in my `doctrine.yaml` :

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
                mapping_types:
                    bit: boolean
                options:
                    timeout: 5
```

I well get the error like `Connection timed out`. BUT, the problem is that it **takes lot of times to timed out**. I set `timeout: 5` to do it but it doesn't seems to change anything, it already wait 30s before timing out.

How can I make the connection failed after 5 seconds instead of 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are the same as passing flags to the driver. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62070107/1456201) shows the values you pass for PDO or MySQLi, however you should be able to use a constant value as a key rather than using the constant's numeric value directly.

For MySQLi:

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                options:
                     - !php/const 'MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT': 5
```

For PDO:

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                options:
                     - !php/const 'PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT': 5
```